# openwater swimming exit with high swell

Tags: swimming, open-water

When there is a high swell in open water at a beach, I understand entering the ocean is a three step procedure - walking (sideways to the waves), duck diving (after waist depth), then swimming (after around two dives, or when the floor is no longer reachable).

I've found then on some days I dive from shoulder-high depth, as the waves break there and are around two meters high.

When exiting, there is a complication that the head is normally in the water. Looking back slows me down. It is rather difficult to assess the size of the waves. I find that often I just stop at shoulder depth and walk from there. In a timed swim this is obviously not the best way to do it.

Do you have any good tips or guides about the exit, please? The main risk is the wave dumping me on the sand. The beach has a step at the exit, it is rather shallow there and I would prefer to avoid it.

I've checked at youtube, but from what I could see there is not a lot of relevant results for people without a surfboard. Most of the results come about surfing. In this question I am interested in the process without a surfboard.

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. Our topics are limited to specific competitive sports only, and while this question may be useful to triathletes and other competitions, it's not clear whether that is your purpose. Can you provide more information on why you would be in the water?

Comment: it will be a timed swim for surflivesaving test (to enter a BM course)

Comment: they have a competition section in the club, but at the moment i'm struggling with meeting the entry requirement

Comment: Is this question for the purpose of sporting competition, then, or for the purpose of a qualification or club membership? (or of course, for both)

Comment: it is for both, I think the technique will be the same.. after I pass then I may be likely to take part in competitions eventually

Comment: I’m presuming body surfing in is out of the question?